Current Transformer: Bifilar Fractional Turn fixed compensation explained
I'm a new design engineer at a company that manufactures current transformers. When we get requests for very high accuracy, high burden CTs with a lower turns ratio (usually 600:5 or less) we're usually forced to use the method in the title to meet the high accuracies vs normal winding methods.
The method is as follows: Using a 600:5 window style CT with one primary turn, 120 secondary turns as an example, we would wind the unit with two parallel wires. 120 turns on the main winding and 119 turns on the compensated winding and connect the starts and finishes of both windings together. We have an old DOS program that was created before i was born that we use to calculate ratio/phase error for turns compensated units.
How it seems to work is it calculates the ratio error of the main winding (120 turns) and the compensated winding (119 turns) and adds them together which results in the ratio error being much smaller than it would have been with just a single 120 turn secondary winding.
Can anyone help to explain the working theory behind this technique? Can't seem to find much/if any documentation on this online.
Edit: added the image below. As you can see the uncompensated winding (600 turns of 12 AWG magnet wire) has a negative ratio error, whereas the compensated winding (599 turns of 11 AWG magnet wire) has a positive ratio error. Sum the two up to get your new ratio error. This may be a bad example because in this case the compensation made the ratio error worse than it would've been with just one 600 turn winding but the program allows you to play around with different wire sizes for the main and compensated windings to get favorable results.
To be clear i'm not asking how the program works because that would be impossible for any of you to know, rather i want to know how the physics behind this works. I don't understand how one winding can have a positive ratio error and the other has a negative one.


I'm intrigued, but don't have much to go on -- I could analyze what the connection does, for instance, but it doesn't seem very useful or pertinent to the performance of a CT. Could you provide more background information on this?: design docs around the DOS program, or references that were used to create it (peruse the library, maybe there are some old documents sitting around?); drawings showing how exactly these transformers are wound; measurements illustrating that the described wiring actually does what it claims; etc.

You might not be able to post a lot of these things, at least not in full, but if it's novel enough, perhaps your company holds a patent on it which can be referenced here. (Conversely, if it's old enough, perhaps there's a business case to be made that the value of those presumed trade secrets is little anymore, whereas developing a working domain knowledge is more valuable. Or, it might still be considered better to bring in a specialist rather than release that.) (A reminder that, releasing drawings here is akin to open-sourcing them per CC-BY-SA 4.0.)

@timwilliams please see the edit to my question. I cannot provide any drawings or white papers. But talking to my technical director, the concept itself is not a trade secret, however the many different applications of the technique could be. As to how they're wound, it's just a simple bifilar winding, two wires wound in parallel. The starts of the windings are connected to the same terminal/lead wire (X1 under IEEE 57.13 terminal marking nomenclature) and the finishes are connected to the same X2 terminal/wire except that one of the wires has one less turn than the other.

Ah, so wire size is a variable quantity. That makes one plausible mechanism then. Are core dimensions also a factor here?

@TimWilliams yes, typical design parameters are factored in: core dimensions, steel type, operating temp, build, wire size, burden of load, power factor, %rated current, etc...
